# Oracle SQL Request - SELECT in SELECT with MAX value

Tags: jquery, sql, oracle, select, join

Could you please help me for creating a view based on history tables?

The context: When an update is done (to a date t), a new line is created (new ID HIST) in the table concerned.

Here the structure of my database:

[image]

ID HIST in the both tables are different and not linked. Only ID Contract are linked.

I would like that the view retrieves all data (thanks to ID_HIST and Date Creation) from the both tables sorted by date. 
If the update concerns the modules table then all last values on the contract corresponding to the last update have to be restrieved) like:

[image]

I'm trying to do that but I have difficulties to implement the part for getting updates on modules joined to the last updates of contracts(last row of contract where contract date < the module date).

**Here the query used**:

```
--- Results List from the contract list
SELECT 
  CONTRACT_HIST_ID HIST_ID,
  CONTRACT_HIST_DT_CRE,
  CONTRACT_ID,
  CONTRACT_TITLE,
  CONTRACT_DESC,
  CONTRACT_BUDGET

from CONTRACT_HIST CT

UNION

--- Results List from the modules list
SELECT 
  DISTINCT(MD.MOD_HIST_ID) HIST_ID,
  MD.MODULE_HIST_DT_CRE,
  CT.CONTRACT_HIST_ID,
  CT.CONTRACT_TITLE,
  CT.CONTRACT_DESC,
  CT.CONTRACT_BUDGET

FROM MODULE_HIST MD
JOIN  
(SELECT CT.CONTRACT_HIST_ID,
  CT.CONTRACT_HIST_ID,
  CT.CONTRACT_TITLE,
  CT.CONTRACT_DESC,
  CT.CONTRACT_BUDGET
  FROM CONTRACT_HIST CT      
  WHERE CT.CONTRACT_HIST_ID in 
  (SELECT MAX(CONT.CONTRACT_HIST_ID) 
      FROM CONTRACT_HIST CONT
      JOIN MODULE_HIST MD
      ON CONT.CONTRACT_HIST_ID=MD.MOD_HIST_CONTRACT_ID
      AND CONT.CONTRACT_HIST_DT_CRE < MD.MODULE_HIST_DT_CRE      
  )  
)CT
ON CT.CONTRACT_ID=MD.MOD_HIST_CONTRACT_ID
```

Comment: this does not work like that. You should try to do it on your own and ask a **specific** question.

Comment: Hi,I have tried but as explained the results on the contract data for the module update are not correctly retrieved ( the last row is still returned and not the last update). Here above my query:

Comment: you cannot make a distinct on a single value...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest that your data model needs improvement.  When you put data into a database, you need to be thinking about how you eventually want to get it back out.  In this case, you should be inserting a "contract version #" into both the Contract History and the Module History tables, so that you can directly inner join the data.

However, given the data model as it is, try this:

```
--- Results List from the contract list
SELECT contract_hist_id hist_id,
       contract_hist_dt_cre,
       contract_id,
       contract_title,
       contract_desc,
       contract_budget
FROM   contract_hist ct
UNION
--- Results List from the modules list
SELECT md.mod_hist_id,
       md.module_hist_dt_cre,
       MAX (ct.contract_hist_id) KEEP (DENSE_RANK LAST ORDER BY cont.contract_hist_dt_cre) contract_hist_id,
       MAX (ct.contract_title) KEEP (DENSE_RANK LAST ORDER BY cont.contract_hist_dt_cte) contract_title,
       MAX (ct.contract_desc) KEEP (DENSE_RANK LAST ORDER BY cont.contract_hist_dt_cte) contract_desc,
       MAX (ct.contract_budget) KEEP (DENSE_RANK LAST ORDER BY cont.contract_hist_dt_cte) contract_budget
FROM   module_hist md
       INNER JOIN contract_hist cont
         ON cont.contract_hist_id = md.mod_his_contract_id
         AND cont.contract_hist_dt_cre < md.module_hist_dt_cre
GROUP BY md.mod_hist_id, md.module_hist_dt_cre;
```

Answer (score 0):

I solve my problem by updating the query:

```
SELECT 
  CONTRACT_HIST_ID HIST_ID,
  CONTRACT_HIST_DT_CRE,
  CONTRACT_ID,
  CONTRACT_TITLE,
  CONTRACT_DESC,
  CONTRACT_BUDGET
FROM CONTRACT_HIST CT

UNION

SELECT DISTINCT(MD.MOD_HIST_ID) HIST_ID,
  MD.MODULE_HIST_DT_CRE,
  MD.MOD_HIST_CONTRACT_ID,
  CT.CONTRACT_TITLE,
  CT.CONTRACT_DESC,
  CT.CONTRACT_BUDGET

FROM MODULE_HIST MD

JOIN CONTRACT_HIST CT ON CT.CONTRACT_ID=MD.MOD_HIST_CONTRACT_ID
AND CT.CONTRACT_HIST_ID = (
  SELECT MAX(CONTRACT_HIST_ID) 
  FROM CONTRACT_HIST
  WHERE CONTRACT_HIST.CONTRACT_ID = MD.MOD_HIST_CONTRACT_ID
  AND CONTRACT_HIST.CONTRACT_HIST_DT_CRE < MD.MODULE_HIST_DT_CRE
  )
```